# SQL - execute query from table cells

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a database with one table, `Queries`. This table has two columns, `name` and `Query`. In column named `Query` I'm recording some SQL statements.

I'm trying to execute these statements after selecting them from the table.

This is my code, but output is incorrect, only the statements listed, without execution:

```
DECLARE @STR_QUERY NVARCHAR(max);
SET @STR_QUERY = 'SELECT Query FROM [AccHelper].[dbo].[Queries]'

EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @STR_QUERY
```

Comment: Remove the quotes around your select statement.

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should help you go through all scripts in that table. With what you are doing, only one script will be run so if the table has 100 Scripts, only one will be executed. Hope this helps

```
DECLARE @Queries TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),SQLScript VARCHAR(MAX))
DECLARE @STR_QUERY VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @StartLoop INT
DECLARE @EndLoop INT


INSERT INTO @Queries
SELECT Query 
FROM [AccHelper].[dbo].[Queries]

SELECT @EndLoop = MAX(ID), @StartLoop = MIN(ID)
FROM @Queries

WHILE @StartLoop < = @EndLoop
BEGIN
    SELECT @STR_QUERY = SQLScript 
    FROM @Queries
    WHERE ID = @StartLoop

    EXEC (@STR_QUERY)

    SET @StartLoop = @StartLoop + 1
END
```

Comment: This is helpful, but my idea is different. I have wpf project with dynamic number of queries who are managed from user. So this user select one and execute to repair something in database with checkbox and button. Little part from SQL support tool.

Answer (score 3):

Try below:

```
DECLARE @STR_QUERY NVARCHAR(max);
SET @STR_QUERY = (SELECT Query FROM [AccHelper].[dbo].[Queries])

EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @STR_QUERY
```

Comment: Thank you so much!