# Is it possible to set value of a column by executing queries stored in another column as string, without using loop?

Tags: sql, sybase

I have a table with 3 columns, column `A` is date in `varchar` form; column `B` is also `varchar`, each cell stores a query that will return a number; column `C` is NULL by default, and is supposed to store values returned by queries.

For each query in column `B`, there is a condition about date and I want to substitute the date by values in column `A`.

I have found an answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43121146/sql-execute-query-from-table-cells), I can achieve my goal by altering answer to that thread

```
CREATE TABLE sample
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    dte VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    SQLScript VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
    num decimal(18,2) DEFAULT NULL
)

DECLARE @STR_QUERY VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @StartLoop INT
DECLARE @EndLoop INT

/*INSERT some rows INTO sample*/

SELECT @EndLoop = MAX(ID), @StartLoop = MIN(ID)
FROM @Queries

WHILE @StartLoop < = @EndLoop
BEGIN
    SELECT @STR_QUERY = REPLACE(SQLScript,'dte',columnA) 
    FROM SAMPLE
    WHERE ID = @StartLoop

    UPDATE SAMPLE
    SET num=EXEC (@STR_QUERY)
    WHERE ID=@StartLoop

    SET @StartLoop = @StartLoop + 1
END
```

However, I'm used to write R and in R If I have a list with a structure similar to the table I described above, I can do the same thing in a more compact, vectorized way without using loop

```
#f is list of functions
f <- list(funs)

#p is list of parameters for functions in f
p <- list(par)

#output is the result returned by calling functions with parameters in p
output <- mapply(function(funs,param){return(funs(param))},f,p)
```

Is it possible to complete the task in Sybase SQL in a similar vectorized way?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to complete the task in Sybase SQL in a similar
> vectorized way?

No.

To get even close you have to use "dynamic sql" (which is what that while loop does).